# how to block number if there is no option for it

Tags: lumia-520, call-sms-filter

I want to block some numbers for some reason but I did not get how to block I saw other answer you gave but there is no option called 'block number' in my windows phone Nokia Lumia 520 now what to do?

Answer (score 4):

If you are on WP 8.1 (Denim update), you can set it easily. Head to settings > call + SMS filter >and turn it ON

Next, tap on phone dialer > long tap on the number you want to block > and tap block number .

That's it.

Comment: What if itS got the denim update but no call + sms filter option in settings?

Comment: @Romello That means you need to install the app. Here is the store URL - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/callsmsfilter/9wzdncrfj3jf

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to block a number, it has to be in your call log. You cannot block a number from the contacts(people) list.

So, the easiest workaround: First dial the number you want to block, for less than a second, so that it appears in the call log (don't let it ring, please..lol). 
Then once it's in the call log, long tap on it, and the block option should be there. If it's not there, you need to activate the feature by going under Setting, then looking for Call + SMS Filter